# Launching Angle of Projectile if Launching and Landing Elevations are Different

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I am given a projectile system in which launching and landing elevations are different. I know the total range, gravity, and initial velocity only. I want to "Derive" a formula for launching angle, but I'm stuck. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can just use the formula which describes which a projectile follows a parabolic path. I've attached the derivation. So, here, x would be the horizontal distance it needs to cover, and y shall be the vertical distance, that is the difference in elevations. Substitute, and solve for the angle of projection. [image]

Comment: Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.